# Printing watson entity found in text (input)

Tags: input, output, response, watson-conversation

I have a situation, where user asks for "I want to buy us dolars". I have already defined the intent for the question "I want to buy". What I need, is to identify which currency user is talking about (buying).
For that, I created an Entity "money", with a value "currency", and its synonyms (us dollar, euros, ienes, ....).
The issue is, that the node recognizes @items:buying and @money:currency. How can I get which currency was found, and use it onto the context/output?

I tried using    and also

but it always returns an empty value.

entities[0] returns me only the buying stuff, the first recognized thing. I need the second, specifically by name, in order to customize my conversation flow.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok let me rewrite that. When I use <? entities['currency']?.toString() ?>, I get the first value of my Entity. I need to know which synonym was matched. Hope that is easier now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, first switch on `@sys-currency` system entity.

After that, this example should work once training is complete.

Condition: `@sys-currency`

Response: `Currency: <? @sys-currency.unit ?>. Total: <? @sys-currency ?>`

[image]

However it assumes that you are writing the currency correctly. For example:

- 20 USD
- $20
- 20 dollars

More details here:

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/system-entities.html#sys-currency-entity

---

To address the other point of finding the value of the recognised text of the entity, you would use:

```
<? entities[0].literal ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not a sys-currency issue. Currency is just the name of my value, in money entity, which I use for user prompt about buying money. Thanks for answering, anyway. Please advice.

Comment: @sys-currency has better recognition than standard entities.

Comment: Ok Simon, let me try to explain this again. I cannot use sys-currency. I am not dealing with client default currency, I am receiving an input question, saying "I want to buy euros". User may be in Brazil, in USA, or even in Japan. Passed that, I need to obtain the array position for that synonym, that is part of a big currency entity.  Did you understand?